# Coolant line leaking water into basement. How do I seal it?

Tags: leak, foundation

My coolant line enters the foundation under ground.  During heavy rains the ground get saturated and water runs inside the insulation into my basement.  What is a good product to seal the outside?  Should I cut away a section of the insulation for a better seal?

Comment: We need a picture. The water must be stopped at the point of entry, so start digging.

Answer (score 0):

Hydraulic cement is normally used on concrete walls and floors to seal them. You would need to clean out any insulation products used in the wall  and on the coolant line.  Having good drainage in this area so water won’t hold at or above the level of the hole may be what is needed and in any case should be done to eliminate leaks.
Dig a foot or more below the leaking line and back fill with gravel the gravel back fill alone may Rx the problem by allowing the water to run off or drain.

Cleaning out the hole and sealing with hydraulic cement would not be my first choice because it usually works but a ac coolant line embedded in concrete will have a shorter life span because the concrete will react with the pipe in most cases.

Comment: Ed, thanks for the gravel suggestion. Removing the insulation & using the hydraulic cement is my concern, too.  I am afraid it would react with the copper line, and then be encased in cement.  Is there some sort of rubberized/synthetic product that might work?

Comment: Digging below the hole a foot and providing a drainage for the water is the best plan I would probably use a silicone sealant on the outside prior to refilling with rock I have seen this work quite well because the water is no longer standing and puddling but draining down.